# Changing Value of variable with click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle the value of "unit" from 'c' to 'f' when pressing a button and I just can't get it to work. I have spent plenty of time looking at alternate examples but would love to know why my solution doesn't work to learn from it. 
I have managed to toggle the value of the button but then couldn't find a way to actually use button.value in the loadweather function. Just using unit: button.value, didn't work. 
Do you have any idea on what might be wrong?

My JS is:

```
var temp = 'c';
function change() {
if (temp == 'f') {temp = 'c';} 
else if (temp == 'c') {temp = 'f';} 
}
$('.btn').on('click', function() { change (); })

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
$.simpleWeather({
location: location,
woeid: woeid,
unit: temp,
success: function(weather) {
  html = '<h2>' + weather.temp + '&deg;' + weather.units.temp + '</h2>';
  html += '<ul><li>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + ', ' + weather.country + '</li>';
  html += '<li class="currently">' + weather.currently + '</li>';
  $("#weather").html(html);
```

And the button html + css looks like this: `<button class = "btn"> Toggle F/C </button>`

```
.btn {
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
background: white;
display: block;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px; 
}
```

Comment: Could create a similar Demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Also try semicolon (;) after $('.btn').on('click', function() { change (); });

Comment: when you are calling `loadWeather`???

Comment: http://codepen.io/ManuelNiederl/pen/qOdNLW Here is the complete example. Sorry for not including it earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing a complete recreation of your issue, I can not be entirely sure this answer is complete. However, I have a feeling the main issue is that you are not recalling `loadWeather()` after changing the variable.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/aaov1scu/**

**JS:**

```
var temp = 'c';

function change() {
    if (temp == 'f') {
        temp = 'c';
    } else if (temp == 'c') {
        temp = 'f';
    }
    loadWeather('Akron, OH', '');
}
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    change();
});

function loadWeather(location, woeid) {
    $.simpleWeather({
        location: location,
        woeid: woeid,
        unit: temp,
        success: function (weather) {
            html = '<h2>' + weather.temp + '&deg;' + weather.units.temp + '</h2>';
            html += '<ul><li>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + ', ' + weather.country + '</li>';
            html += '<li class="currently">' + weather.currently + '</li>';
            $("#weather").html(html);
        }
    });
}
loadWeather('Akron, OH', '');
```

Comment: This works great but it unfortunately breaks the location functionality. I guess I have to recall the loadWeather function only at specific places but I'm at a loss to where. Here is a link to the Codepen: http://codepen.io/ManuelNiederl/pen/qOdNLW

Comment: @ManuelNiederl Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/aaov1scu/1/ This version might be a bit easier to understand. I changed the `loadWeather` function a bit so a location does not have to be set every time it is called. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @ManuelNiederl Here is a corrected version of your codepen: http://codepen.io/techsock/pen/qObQYy Also, don't forget to select an accepted answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

not sure why your code isn't working for you.

I pasted into a jsbin and it works for me.

Please take a look here: http://jsbin.com/foheguzevo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Found an issue - `<script>` block in document should be after `<button>`. Better after the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Script should looks like this:

```js
var temp = 'c';
function change() {
    temp = temp == 'f' ? 'c' : 'f';
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', function() { change(); });
});
```

`$(document).ready()` will add event listener only after all elements will be loaded and created.